# Why does the Visual Studio 2010 compiler not know __func__?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The title says it all. It knows

- `__FUNCTION__`: naked name of function
- `__FUNCSIG__`: complete name of function (with return type and parameters)
- `__FUNCDNAME__`: mangled name of function

but not `__func__` although it is [part of the C99 standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html). I want my code to be platform independent, so I hesitate to use one of the above. Do you have any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Microsoft has only very recently started (partially) supporting C99 - you need to upgrade to VS 2015.

Comment: It works just fine in VS2015.  If your VS version is old, and VS2010 is certainly geriatric in gcc years, then no, you can't count on C99 compliance.  Cross-platform code is always peppered with #if, you just need another one to check `_MSC_VER` and `#define __func__ __FUNCTION__`.  Or update, you'll have to sooner or later so better make it sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsofts support of C99 has always been pretty sketchy, at best.

According to this [predefined macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) list on the Microsoft website it is supported in Visual Studio 2015. It looks like the earliest version that supported it was Visual Studio 2013, so you'll probably need to upgrade if you really need to use that macro.